# Select a given window on any workspace?

Tags: windows, keybindings, mission-control

I have lots of terminals for different things. I have a keybinding to switch to a the terminal app, but I find that I have lots of different terminal windows across lots of workspaces.

Is there a way to switch to a specific window on a specific desktop?

**Approaches tried:**
I tried using hammerspoon for this - but you can't reliably see windows on different desktops.

Comment: How do you identify the different windows? Whatever method you use, it needs to know which window to switch to.

Comment: You can set the title of a window via terminal escape codes, so that might work. Alternative it could be nice to select a window with some sort of interface.